# How to force Conda to use pipenv environment?

Tags: python, conda, pipenv

I want to combine using pipenv and codna environment. Can I force conda to use the already created pipenv environment?

Comment: That doesn't make sense. It isn't clear exactly what behavior you are seeking, or why you would need to combine conda and pipenv...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga We have developers in one project using pipenv and conda. We all want to shift towards Pipfiles, but some dont want to abandon conda environments.

Comment: Those are competing python environments, I'm sure they both offer pros and cons. You wouldn't want to install one inside the other, it seems redundant. I use pipenv over conda, as I've run into issues with using conda on ARM-based systems. you can do it, but it's not natively supported. I see what your trying to do, but I wouldn't recommend it.. not sure how you would go about doing what your looking for.

Comment: Why is `virtualenv` tagged?

Comment: @merv Because Conda and Pipenv are both virtualenv managers? The OP wants to make them to manage a single virtualenv but they're incompatible and want to manage their own virtualenvs.

Comment: Those are mutually exclusive tools, as far as I know. They are not meant to work together.

Comment: @phd no, `virtualenv` is a seperate tool, conda does *not* manage `virtualenv`. `pipenv` is a tool that is used to manage `virtualenv` along with `pip` together.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga `virtualenv` as a separate tool — yes, it's separate. But the concept of virtual environments is built into Python and there're many tools to manage them. `python -m venv`, `virtualenv`, `virtualenvwrapper` (can use either `venv` or `virtualenv`), `pipenv`, `pipx`, `pyenv-virtualenv`, `conda`…

Comment: @phd right, but the *tag* `virtualenv` is specifically about the tool `vitualenv`. But I suspect you are right that the OP meant to tag for the general concept of virtual environmnets